# NSPopover relative to NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenuitem, nsmenu, nspopover

I'm working on an OSX application which uses a NSMenu to display content.
I'd like to make a NSPopover appear when an NSMenuItem is highlighted, but I'm stucked with the "showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:" part as I don't have a relative view to pass as "ofView" argument.

Is there a way to do that easily? 
The Droplr application does that (http://d.pr/i/GWrf) so I guess there is...

Thanks !

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm looking for a similar implementation for NSPopOver